# Copy one table data to another database table in same server Azure Services

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure Service database server. Server has databases. by mistakenly , one database table data was deleted. now i want to restore the data from my other database table exist in same server.
i know, azure services do not allow to do this. but is there any possibility or any resolution for better solution.

ServeDB
-> db1(users table data deleted)
-> db2 (i want to recover from users table data from this database,exist in same server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bcp utility to export the table to a local drive in your computer.

```
bcp NLayerApp.dbo.Customer out "C:\MyFolderPath\Customer.txt" -T -c -S WIN7VS2010RC1\SQLEXPRESS
```

Then you can import it to the other database using the same utility.

```
bcp TestDB.dbo.Customer in "C:\MyFolderPath\Customer.txt" -c -U mysqlazureuser@mysqlazureservername -S tcp:mysqlazureservername.database.windows.net -P mypassword
```

You can learn more about bcp [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2010/06/04/importingexporting-data-to-sql-azure-databases-using-bcp-and-sql-scripts/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular Import/Export wizard of SSMS, the same as you would do with a database on premise.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/exporting-data-from-sql-azure-importexport-wizard/

Comment: It is not showing Import option under task. there are options, extract data tier, register for data tier , upgrade for data tier.

Comment: Perhaps, you can run a wizard by right clicking on  a local database, but then point Azure databases as both: source and destination. 
".NET Framework Data Provider for SqlServer." to be used as the data source and destinations in a copy wizard